# Can you include variables in a HTTP request sent to google maps matrix api?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I am kind of new to programming (clearly), and I am working on a project where I need to get the estimated travel time between two places, and I have decided to use the google maps API to do this. I want to send an HTTP request whenever my user presses a button. Here is an example code on Google's Matrix Website

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Now, what I want to do, is send a request like this, but using variables in my application. For example, do something like

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=(VARIABLE HERE WITH PLACE)|(VARIABLE HERE WITH PLACE)|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Thank you in advance, I have tried to find this answer ons tack overflow, However the answers that I found were either not in swift, or not not addressing an HTTP request like this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't send "variables". you're sending query parameters. the url is just a string. build it in your app with whatever values you want.

Comment: Okay, so when I think you are saying is that I can do insert these parameters like in a string such as /(location1) and what not. Is this correct?

Comment: google only sees the url. there is absolutely no way for it to tell the difference between `url = '?foo=bar'` and `url = '?foo='  + somevar`